# Footer not being included with body, when in html its between the body tags. Specifically box shadow isn't including the footer

Tags: html, css

In CSS I'm having an issue where the footer isn't being included with the `body` when in html, the footer is in between the `body` tags. I have a box-shadow border for the whole body, but the footer doesn't have the box shadow around it. As seen below the footer tags are in between the body tags and in the CSS code the body has box shadows, but the footer doesnt have a box shadow. Here's the code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> The Halloween Store </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <img src="favicon.ico" alt="Pumpkin" height="80">
    <h2>The Halloween Store</h2>
    <h3>For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <h1> Welcome to my site. Please come in and stay awhile. </h1>
    <p>I started this website because Halloween has always been my favorite holiday. But during the last year, I started selling some of my favorite Halloween products, and they've become quite a hit.
    </p>
    <p>If you click on the Personal link, you can browse my favorite Halloween pictures, stories, and films. And if you join my email list, I will keep you up-to-date on all things Halloween.
    </p>

    <h3>Product categories</h3>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="Products/Props.html">Props</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Costumes.html">Costumes</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Special_effects.html">Special Effects</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Masks.html">Masks</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>My guarantee</h3>

    <p>If you aren't completely satisfied with everything you buy from my site, you can return it for a full refund. <b>No questions asked!</b> </p>

  </main>

  <footer>

    <p>&copy; 2016 Ben Murach</p>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see the footer included within the body in the example shown here...

Comment: That's what I don't get, the box shadow should be going around the footer too.

Comment: There is no probleme in your example here.

Answer (score 1):

A box-shadow is *outside*  the border. So if it's on the `body`element, and that `body` fully fills or even overflows the screen (fully filling the `html` element), the box-shadow will be cut off, even if `box-sizing` is defined as `border-box`, since that only includes the content area, the padding and the border, but not margins and box-shadows.

The snippet area here is less wide than the 800px you defined as `width` for `body`, so that already extends the width of the viewport (i.e. the snippet area), and also the height is more than the default height of the snippet area.

However, if you make your `body` element narrower than the screen or the html element, and apply some `padding-bottom` to the `html` element, there will be space for the `body`s box-shadow:

```css
html {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
body {
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 550px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> The Halloween Store </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <img src="favicon.ico" alt="Pumpkin" height="80">
    <h2>The Halloween Store</h2>
    <h3>For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <h1> Welcome to my site. Please come in and stay awhile. </h1>
    <p>I started this website because Halloween has always been my favorite holiday. But during the last year, I started selling some of my favorite Halloween products, and they've become quite a hit.
    </p>
    <p>If you click on the Personal link, you can browse my favorite Halloween pictures, stories, and films. And if you join my email list, I will keep you up-to-date on all things Halloween.
    </p>

    <h3>Product categories</h3>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="Products/Props.html">Props</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Costumes.html">Costumes</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Special_effects.html">Special Effects</a></li>
      <li><a href="Products/Masks.html">Masks</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>My guarantee</h3>

    <p>If you aren't completely satisfied with everything you buy from my site, you can return it for a full refund. <b>No questions asked!</b> </p>

  </main>

  <footer>

    <p>&copy; 2016 Ben Murach</p>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```